# Error when Installing Playwright with yarn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, playwright, preact

The following error appears once I run `yarn create playwright --ct` on a react project; the documentation also says that after running that command some files are generated but they were not.

Any help is appreciated

```
bash: line 1: _modules.binplaywright: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command failed: yarn playwright install
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:871:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:943:15)
    at executeCommands (\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\create-playwright\lib\index.js:4519:39)
    at Generator.run (\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\create-playwright\lib\index.js:4660:5)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async \AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\create-playwright\lib\index.js:4928:3 {
  status: 127,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 17900,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
```

Tried to delete node_modules and reinstall it but didn't work

Comment: Did you try npm?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to install it manually:

```
# add playwright package
yarn add -E -D @playwright/test
# install supported browsers
ynpx playwright install
```

Make sure 'ynpx' is installed globally, otherwise install it.

```
yarn global add ynpx
```

and use `playwright.config.ts` file at the root of your project:

```js
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
// require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: 'e2e_tests',

  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI || true,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: [['html', { open: 'never' }]],
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry'
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] }
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] }
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] }
    }

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
    // },
  ]

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  // webServer: {
  //   command: 'npm run start',
  //   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  //   reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  // },
});
```